# ¿Se puede "manipular" la apariencia o contenido de la página sólo con javascript sin recargar la página?

Tags: javascript, django

Estoy haciendo un proyecto personal, con Django, y otras tecnología. Entonces  con Django sirvo un tamplate (*no sé si estaré usando las palabras técnicas adecuadas, me disculpan*) junto con un diccionario mediante los métodos de la views, algo así:

```
def home_view(request):
    '''List existing posts.'''    
    a = ContentManagementTextFiles()        
    return render(request, 'book.html',a)
```

**a** sería el dicionario, que contiene de forma anidada otros diccionarios, con todo el contenido de muchos libros, separados con sus capítulos, y sus contenidos. Ya está probado y bien organizado

La idea que tenía era pasar ese diccionario en formato JSON, y luego en el navegador cliente convertirlo a un objeto JavaScript, y mediante JavaScript, visualizar todo, según el usuario opte por ver. Es decir, todo el contenido, estará en ese objeto, y si el usuario quiere ver un libro lo escoge desde unos controles select (también administrados a través de JavaScript), y se le enseña. 
Pero mi duda está en que si JavaScript, pueda hacer eso sin que se vuelva a recargar la página, sin que el servidor web en el backend se entere. Gracias

Comment: Si. Javascript puede manipular todo el DOM sin necesidad de que se recargue la página. Imprimir el Json en una variable javascript y luego haz un each, llama a un div y imprime los libros o elementos que quieras. Si tienes más dudas te haré un ejemplo después.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ya lo hice y funciona bien. Aunque parece que tendré que usar AJAX (según he leído) para actualizar los datos en el servidor, para saber por ejemplo en que página de tal libro se quedó el usuario cuando cerró el navegador.

Comment: También puedes usar localstorage

Comment: localstorage sería un gran error, pues en el momento que refresques caché pierdes todos los avances.

Answer (score 0):

Requieres usar como mínimo AJAX para cargar datos de forma dinámica.

Para la primera carga de los datos, a partir de Django 2.1 tienes la etiqueta [json-script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script.) como forma oficial de cargar en una variable javascript un objeto Python en formato JSON.